# Difference between wrapping jQuery blocks by starting with "jQuery(function..." vs ending with " })(jQuery);"

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I've just started learning jQuery and was wondering what the difference was between a chunk of jQuery code wrapped like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //code here
});
```

vs wrapping like this:

```
(function ($) {
    //code here
})(jQuery);
```

... or if there is a difference at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an important difference, the first is a DOM ready handler, it waits until the document is ready and all elements can be accessed.

The second one is just an [immediately invoked function expression](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/#immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife), it executes immediately and *does* ***not*** wait for the document to be ready.

Both of them creates a local scope where the value of `$` equals `jQuery`